# What is the data type returned by the following SOSL search

Tags: sosl

While preparing for DEV450 I got below question in one of the sample test

> What is the data type returned by the following SOSL search? `[FIND 'Acme*' IN NAME FIELDS RETURNING Account, Opportunity];`
>
> A - `List<List<Account>,List<Opportunity>>`
> B- `Maps<sObject,sObject>`
> C- `Map<Id,sObject>`
> D- `List<List<sObject>>`

My asnwer was D but answer provided by test was B, can someone please explain whats the correct answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can confirm that it is D by running:

```
Object o = [FIND 'Acme*' IN NAME FIELDS RETURNING Account, Opportunity];
System.assert(o instanceOf List<List<SObject>>);
```

Answer (score 1):

The [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_dynamic_sosl.htm) states that the return type is `List<List<SObject>>`, so (D) would technically be the correct answer. (B) is definitely **not** the correct answer, as there is no data type called `Maps`.